# Fortran functions returning characters

Tags: function, fortran, character

I have a function that returns a character string. In Fortran there is
a requirement that the length of the output s has to be defined and cannot
be (`len=*)`. I am not sure what problems I might get into when I call
a function and the string is shorter or longer that the size declared in the
function.

```
Function real_to_str_new  &
  (                       &
    r, fmt                &
  )                       &
    Result (s)

Real, Intent(in) :: r
Character (len=*), Intent(in) :: fmt

Character (len=65) :: s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That there is a function result isn't very important, and the question follows rules of assignment.

In (intrinsic) assignment where you have `variable = expr` for character types, the rules [7.2.1.3, 10](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) are:

> For an intrinsic assignment statement where the variable is of type character, the expr may have a different character length parameter in which case the conversion of expr to the length of the variable is as follows.
>
> (1) If the length of the variable is less than that of expr, the value of expr is truncated from the right until it is the same length as the variable.
>
> (2) If the length of the variable is greater than that of expr, the value of expr is extended on the right with blanks until it is the same length as the variable.

In this case `expr` (as the function result) has length parameter 65 and `variable` will have length parameter as declared (unless `allocatable` comes into play).

Comment: Well yeah---the Standard... I wouldn't build on the Standard in this particular case! I spent many an hour to debug code where longer strings than expected were given to a function/subroutine. It seems that at least `gfortran` doesn't always perform the truncation correctly, resulting in writing something into memory where it doesn't belong---you can imagine the result. Better to make sure the string lengths match.

Comment: In this case (although your experience sounds interesting), this isn't related to function/subroutine _arguments_.